# Ruby: Syntax for defining a constant inside a Struct

Tags: ruby

Consider the following (correct) Ruby program:

```
class Outer

  Inner = Struct.new(:dummy) do
    CONST = 'abce'
    def fun
      puts(dummy)
    end
  end

end

obj = Outer::Inner.new(15)
obj.fun
puts(Outer::CONST)
```

Why do I have to write `Outer::CONST` instead of `Outer::Inner::CONST`?

My understanding of the block passed to `Struct::new` was that `self` is bound to `Outer::Inner`, and indeed, we can see that the method (`fun`) is attached to the Inner class; but `CONST` obviously is not.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This happens because the constant is defined in the current *namespace*. The `class` and `module` keywords define namespaces, but `Struct.new` (just like `Class.new`) does not.

In order to define the constant under the Struct's scope, you have to use `self::`

```
class Outer
  Inner = Struct.new(:dummy) do
    self::CONST = 'abce'
  end
end

Outer::Inner::CONST
#=> 'abce'

Outer::CONST
#=> NameError uninitialized constant Outer::CONST
```

Answer (score 1):

After a little digging I was able to figure this out. Here's a quote from a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14260931/ruby-accessing-constants-from-inner-class):

> Constants belong to classes, therefore constant resolution via the ::
>   operator only works with class objects.

In your above example `Inner` is a constant not a class, so `Outer::Inner::CONST` won't work. If we redefine `Inner` as a class we see the expected results.

```
class Outer

  class Inner
    CONST = 'abce'
    Deeper = Struct.new(:dummy) do
      def fun
        puts(dummy)
      end
    end
  end

end

obj = Outer::Inner::Deeper.new(15)
obj.fun
puts(Outer::Inner::CONST)
```

Comment: `Inner` is a class as proved by `Inner.class #=> Class` and the documentation for `Struct` clearly states that this will be a subclass of `Struct`. I think this might have more to do with it [`Module#module_eval`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Module.html#method-i-module_eval) "Evaluates the string or block in the context of mod, **except that when a block is given, constant/class variable lookup is not affected**. This can be used to add methods to a class...."  Since `Struct` sub classes created with a block do so through `rb_mod_module_eval`.

Comment: A small point: it is modules (including classes) that house constants.